# Error when the Grpc server return the data to the grpc client

Tags: c#, grpc, .net-5

i have ,net 5 api that contains a  grpc class when the clinet send request to the grpc server  and the server send response to the client   an exceptoin accure  on the client

**Error Details :**

> Status(StatusCode="Cancelled", Detail="Error starting gRPC call. HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. IOException: The request was aborted. Http2StreamException: The HTTP/2 server reset the stream. HTTP/2 error code 'CANCEL' (0x8).", DebugException="System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request.
> ---> System.IO.IOException: The request was aborted.
> ---> System.Net.Http.Http2StreamException: The HTTP/2 server reset the stream. HTTP/2 error code 'CANCEL' (0x8).
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> at System.Net.Http.Http2Connection.ThrowRequestAborted(Exception innerException)
> at System.Net.Http.Http2Connection.Http2Stream.CheckResponseBodyState()
> at System.Net.Http.Http2Connection.Http2Stream.TryEnsureHeaders()
> at System.Net.Http.Http2Connection.Http2Stream.ReadResponseHeadersAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at System.Net.Http.Http2Connection.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> at System.Net.Http.Http2Connection.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Grpc.Net.Client.Balancer.Internal.BalancerHttpHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Grpc.Net.Client.Internal.GrpcCall`2.RunCall(HttpRequestMessage request, Nullable`1 timeout)")

i set kestral  configuration on the server side  like below

```
.ConfigureKestrel(options =>
                     {
                         options.Listen(IPAddress.Any, 5001, listenOptions =>
                         {
                             listenOptions.Protocols = HttpProtocols.Http2;
                        
                         });
                     })
```

in the client side  i used this method

```
       public async Task Test() {
            try
            {
                AppContext.SetSwitch("System.Net.Http.SocketsHttpHandler.Http2UnencryptedSupport", true);
                AppContext.SetSwitch("System.Net.Http.SocketsHttpHandler.Http2Support", true);
                using var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("https://localhost:44347");
                var client = new Greeter.GreeterClient(channel);
                var reply = await client.SayHelloAsync(
                                  new HelloRequest { Name = "GreeterClient" });

                var result = reply.Message;
            }
            catch (Exception ex )
            {

                throw;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Exception looks like it is from client.  Can you capture same on server?

Comment: the server recive the request and return the response and exsite the function

i need to highlight that i worke  on local machine the server is  .net 5 api and the client is a .net worker

Comment: Still we need more info on the root cause of issue.  The exception does not give any clues to what is causing the error.   There are too many reasons for the failure to start guessing.  There are lots of reasons for code to work on a local host and then fail on a Net 5 server.